# При формировании PDF программно появляются странные точки

Tags: pdf

Формирую pdf файл при помощи библиотеки AlivePdf (делаю это во Flash через ActionScript).
Проблема в том, что рисунок засорен какими-то странными точками.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом эти точки исчезают, если я сильно увеличу масштаб, они не выводятся на лист при печати. Но в Pdf почему-то присутствуют.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, в чём проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Причина следующая: AlivePdf написана кривыми руками.
В общем, не надо использовать функцию lineTo. Вместо неё в самой поздней версии есть функция drawLine. Она не глючит. Рисование при помощи moveTo-lineTo глючит постоянно (например, при попытке нарисовать штриховую линию, она будет выводиться с разной толщиной линий, разной длинной штрихов, разной шириной зазоров).
И ещё имейте в виду: на сайте AlivePdf почему-то выложена странная библиотека - то есть функции, которые они пишут, что реализованы, в скачиваемой библиотеке не реализованы. Я нашёл библиотеку с реализованными функциями на гитхабе у одного умельца. В общем, гуглите и не сотанавливайтесь, пока не найдёте библиотеку со всеми реализованными задокументированными функциями.